# Defaultdict() the correct choice?

Tags: defaultdict

EDIT: mistake fixed

The idea is to read text from a file, clean it, and pair *consecutive* words (not permuations):

```
file = f.read()
words = [word.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for word in file.split()]
pairs = [(words[i]+" " + words[i+1]).split() for i in range(len(words)-1)]
```

Then, for each pair, create a list of all the possible *individual* words that can follow that pair throughout the text.  The dict will look like

```
[ConsecWordPair]:[listOfFollowers]
```

Thus, referencing the dictionary for a given pair will return all of the words that can follow that pair.  E.g.

```
wordsThatFollow[('she', 'was')]
>> ['alone', 'happy', 'not']
```

My algorithm to achieve this involves a **defaultdict(list)**...

```
wordsThatFollow = defaultdict(list) 

for i in range(len(words)-1):
    try:
        # pairs overlap, want second word of next pair
        # wordsThatFollow[tuple(pairs[i])] = pairs[i+1][1]
        EDIT: wordsThatFollow[tuple(pairs[i])].update(pairs[i+1][1][0]
    except Exception:
        pass
```

I'm not so worried about the value error I have to circumvent with the 'try-except' (unless I should be).  The problem is that the algorithm **only successfully returns one of the followers**:

```
wordsThatFollow[('she', 'was')]
>> ['not']
```

Sorry if this post is bad for the community I'm figuring things out as I go ^^

Comment: You want to change `wordsThatFollow[tuple(pairs[i])] = pairs[i+1][1]` to `wordsThatFollow[tuple(pairs[i])].append(pairs[i+1][1])` <- you want to add to the list that is the value of the pair, not redefine it's value on every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are always overwriting the value, when you really want to *extend* it:

```
# Instead of this
wordsThatFollow[tuple(pairs[i])] = pairs[i+1][1]

# Do this
wordsThatFollow[tuple(pairs[i])].append(pairs[i+1][1])
```

Comment: The funny thing is the moment I post this I look back over and suddenly realize this very thing.  Probably time for a break.  Thanks Sean